# Pointer to a derived class C++

Tags: class, pointers, derived

I'm having some trouble with deriving a pointer to a derived class.  I think it has something to do with a constructor.  Do I have to create a new constructor in my derived class?  How to I create a pointer from a derived class?   Thanks

```
 Class Base
 {
   public:



   int myfunction(int a,int b,int c)
   {
   return a+b+c;
   }
 };

 Class Derived: public Base
{
  int newfunction(int a, int b, int c)
  {
   return a*b*c;
  };

};


int main()
{
// this doesn't work at all.. I get all errors every time I try to refer to the object
//instantiated from my derived class.
//I know it's my lack of understanding.


Derived *NewObject = new Derived;

//Why wont this work?


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ is case sensitive, and the keyword `class` is lowercase. You wrote `Class` for both classes, and it looks like it's the only issue with your code.

Comment: That's just a typo in the example. I can't paste the actual code because I'm deriving a class from some open source software (FLTK) actually and I can't seem to declare a new class from it.  There's probably too much code and will convolude the process.

Comment: Can you do this with the base class?

Comment: @user3523966: my bet is that the issue is with allocating the object, not assigning it to a pointer. Does just `new Derived` work? If it doesn't, then you should give us more info, like the error your compiler shows.